Filter db entries with empty string
I'm using Hibernate 6, Oracle DB, Postgresql DB.
I need to get entries from table where "description" (nvarchar(255)) column is empty.
I know Oracle does not know empty string, it stores it as NULL values.
But how to do it in Hibernate so it works in any DB? (that is whole purpose of Hibernate)
            CriteriaBuilder cb = hibSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<TestObjectDAO> criteria = cb.createQuery(TestObjectDAO.class);
            Root<TestObjectDAO> root = criteria.from(TestObjectDAO.class);
            criteria.select(root);
            criteria.where(
                    cb.notEqual(root.get("description"), ""),
                    cb.isNotNull(root.get("description")),
                    cb.equal(root.get("status"), 0),
                    cb.notEqual(root.get("deleted"), false)
                );
            criteria.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("name")));
            
            Query<TestObjectDAO> query = hibSession.createQuery(criteria);
            List<TestObjectDAO> objects= query.getResultList();

In postgresql it returns rows as expected. But I get no rows from Oracle.
Problem is in cb.notEqual(root.get("description"), ""), when I exclude it, Oracle returns rows correctly as well. But then it does not work in postgresql.
How to do it, so it doesn't matter which DB is used?

I don't use Hibernate nor PostgreSQL. Though: how about checking string length? If it is 0, it is empty (is it not?).

This is the problem with ORMs like Hibernate: they limit you to using SQL constructs that are universal - only the most basic commands. For concepts like "empty" that are specific to only some databases, they don't translate for you - you're just expected to not use what isn't universal in the first place. The lowest possible common denominator. In so doing they severely limit any application's ability to leverage the real power of it's database. If you're paying for a DB license (like Oracle) that's throwing most of that investment value right down the drain.

@Littlefoot very nice idea. This workaround works, at least for Oracle and Postgresql. Hopefully it will work even for MySQL or MSSQL.

Thanks to comments, which directed me towards solution.
There are 2 problems in my code. First is the one I described, and the second one is with the boolean condition. This is the working code:
        CriteriaBuilder cb = hibSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<TestObjectDAO> criteria = cb.createQuery(TestObjectDAO.class);
        Root<TestObjectDAO> root = criteria.from(TestObjectDAO.class);
        criteria.select(root);
        criteria.where(
                cb.greaterThan(cb.length(root.get("description")), 0), // THIS LINE CHANGED
                cb.equal(root.get("status"), 0),
                cb.not(cb.isTrue(root.get("deleted"))) // THIS LINE CHANGED
            );
        criteria.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("name")));
        
        Query<TestObjectDAO> query = hibSession.createQuery(criteria);
        List<TestObjectDAO> objects= query.getResultList();

